# I want to repeat a process in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
var flakeImage = new Image();
 function loadImage(){
    flakeImage.onload = drawFlake;
     flakeImage.src = "game/snowflake.png";
}
```

and this one that initialises the image

```
function initFlake() {
  flakex = Math.random()*(WIDTH-140)+70;
  flakey = (Math.random()*20)+70;
  flakes = Math.random()*40;
}
```

and this one that updates the image so it will look like it s actually falling

```
    function updateFlake(){
    flakey = flakey + 1;
}
```

and also the draw function

```
 function drawFlake() {
      context.drawImage(flakeImage, flakex, flakey, flakes, flakes);
}
```

I want to make it look like it s snowing in my canvas. I can't use a for loop because it will just modify the same picture . I tried making a big array with the same picture, but in the end I don't get that effect .. because the images have to keep falling randomly . How should I combine an array with that image stored at random positions with an interval to get that effect ?

Comment: You need to use time intervals `setInterval(function, delay)`

Comment: That is not enough. Time interval repeats the same image. You need an array full of images that will repeat and keep repeating .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval).

```
doSomething: function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        // update flake position
        updateFlake();
    }, timeInMilliseconds); 
},
```

This runs the function given as a parameter every `timeInMilliseconds` milliseconds. The `setInterval()` function returns an ID which you can pass to `clearInterval()` in order to stop updating.

You can also pass a function directly.

```
doSomething: function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(updateFlake, timeInMilliseconds); 
},
```

---

EDIT: OP, you can do this just fine without relying on HTML5 canvas, instead use DOM elements:

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/wugoyipire/1/)

Javascript:

```
        function update () {
            var myInterval = null;
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                // update flake position
                $("#holder > img").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).position().top >= $(window).height()) 
                        $(this).remove();
                    else 
                        $(this).css({top: $(this).position().top+=3});      
                });
            }, 50); //update each of the drawn children
        }

        function drawFlake() {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            var myInterval = null;

            myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                var randX = (Math.floor((Math.random() * $(window).width()) + 1));
                var $img = $('<img>');
                $img.attr('src','flake.png');
                $("#holder").append($img);                  
                $img.css({left: randX, top: 0, position:'absolute'});
            }, 2000);   //draw a new flake every 2 seconds  

            update();
        }
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="drawFlake()">
    <div id="holder"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
        body {
            background: white;
        }

        #holder {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: @Pietu1998 thanks for the edit- far more detailed :)

Comment: I know about interval function and I am using it, but I only have 1 picture which has to be all over my canvas (1024 width) falling down like snow . And another pictures that will follow shortly(also random). I want to simulate snowing with that.   I just posted the pieces of code that might be relevant in finding a solution for that.

Comment: @iDaniel19 Do you have to use canvas? this can be done easily with the DOM

Comment: Hi Daniel does this answer your question? Please accept if so